# Can I fill a grid container from the center?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Is there a way to fill a grid from the center?

I have a CSS grid container which has a dynamic content(it gets updated so the number of children is not fixed) that looks like this:

```css
#container { 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr));
}
```

and if I had all 4 columns filled it would look like this :

```
1 2 3 4 //Numbers that represent containers children
```

Which is okay for me, but the problem comes when I have, for instance, only two divs inside my main container and then it looks like this:

```
1 2 0 0
```

And what I would like to achieve is this:

```
0 1 2 0
```

Comment: and what will you do if you have only one child and 4 columns?

Comment: I don't know what your use case is, but using flexbox is usually an easier solution to center them.

Comment: @TemaniAfif  0 1 0 0

Comment: @Rod911 , I will look into that, but am still focusing on grid first.

Comment: Why not have your dynamic content for cells 1 and 4 simply be `&nbsp;`? Then the divs would be there, but not display anything.

Comment: They're is no simple way to do this dynamically. I suppose it might be possible with quantity queries though but that seems like a lot of work.

Comment: @Ognjen Check my new answer. It is `grid` based solution but, assumes max 4 columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**NEW ANSWER:**

If you want to stick to just `grid` and **assuming you only have four columns and the possible configurations are `0 1 0 0`, `0 1 1 0`, `0 1 1 1`, `1 1 1 1` then following CSS works:**

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
}

.col {
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}

.col:first-child {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}

.col:first-child:nth-last-child(4) {
  grid-column-start: 1;
}
```

Assuming the HTML you have:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
  Col
  </div>
  <!-- Other Cols Here -->
</div>
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ogu029md/1/)

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

For grids, it's not possible to center a dynamic number of elements. ***Grid layout is suitable for layouts with a fixed number of elements.***

Refer to the use of [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) vs [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) layouts. Your problem is more suitable to be solved by flex where you use `justify-content: center` on flex containers to achieve centered children.

To achieve centered children, modify your styles on `#container` div:

```
#container { 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

**Scenario where you want `0 1 0 0`, `0 1 1 0`, `0 1 1 1`, `1 1 1 1` and assuming there are only four columns**:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.col {
  width: 25%;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}

.col:last-child:not(:nth-child(even)):first-child {
  margin-left: -25%;
}

.col:last-child:not(:nth-child(even)):not(:first-child) {
  margin-right: -25%;
}
```

I assume your markup will be something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
  Col
  </div>
  <!-- Other Columns Go Here -->
</div>
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fh9zr58x/)

Comment: @Paulie_D Perhaps the addition of code might help change your decision? I guess you would have been more helpful if you had also mentioned what would you have liked to see in my answer. :)

Comment: @MuhammadTalhaAkbar Please don't pester people about votes. Votes are anonymous - you cannot be sure where a vote came from and constant nagging is not going to help reverse the vote. At your reputation level, a single downvote is not going to affect you much anyway.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I guess you're right. I'll take care next time.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks for your feedback and I see this scenario was discussed in the comments and not in the original question. See my edits to cater that scenario or scenario with `3 columns`.

Comment: I have now added `grid` only solution with the assumption of 4 columns.

Answer (score 1):

As everyone already stated Flexbox is much suited for this, However *(if i'm not missing anything)*

A combination of the following properties should do the trick

```
grid-auto-flow: column;
grid-auto-columns: 25%; // assumes 4 columns
justify-content: center;
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input')[0].onclick = () => { document.querySelector('[container]').append(document.createElement('div'))}
document.querySelectorAll('input')[1].onclick = () => {document.querySelector('[container]').innerHTML = '<div></div>';}
```

```css
body * {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

[container] {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: 25%;
  justify-content: center;
}

[container]>div {
  height: 50px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Add Column" />
<input type="button" value="reset" />
<div container>
  <div></div>
</div>
```